# Does IIS 7.5 Support AES-256?

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate, iis-7.5

I am looking to create an AES-256 SSL certificate.

Is this supported by IIS 7.5?

Comment: The symmetric algorithm (AES in this case) has nothing to do with the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [THIS](http://derek858.blogspot.com/2010/06/enable-tls-12-aes-256-and-sha-256-in.html) excellent set of instructions of just how to do that.